# I get ever a false date in SqLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

I save a Date and this is ever 1698-19-20 and not 2012-4-12. Here one sees the error? 
Date saved as Integer.

calculated with the calculator:
1334262386066 millisecond

42.309182713914 year + 1970 Year = ~2012

Code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date date = cal.getTime();
calendarEntity.setDate(date);
```

sqlite query:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d',DATE) FROM CALENDAR_ENTITY
```

Table:

```
  CREATE TABLE 'CALENDAR_ENTITY' ('_id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,'TITLE' TEXT,'NOTICE'        TEXT,'DATE' INTEGER,'BABY_ID' INTEGER NOT NULL )
```

Comment: It should be 2012-4-12, but I get 1698-19-20. In Debugger is it right, only in the database, it is wrong.

Comment: It works fine I think at least in my computer. Did you try print this date object to see what is sending to database ?

Comment: I used greenDao as framework for ORM, in java.util.Date format.

Comment: Is strftime working properly ? I don't think there is 19th month in calender.

Comment: This Date is 1334262386066 without strftime.

Comment: Shouldn't date be a long in your table?

Comment: This saved from framework in int

Comment: 1698-19-20 is it with strftime

Comment: Sorry -- sqlite uses integers of various sizes depending on magnitude.  If you meant 1968 and not 1698, then it looks a lot like a long date truncated to an int.

Comment: 1334262386066 millisecond: 42.309182713914 year + 1970 Year = ~2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use this return long like this I think your problem will solved itself.

```
Date date = new Date(1334262386066l);
```

This will return what you expected. And this is what it prints

```
Thu Apr 12 23:26:26 EEST 2012
```

Comment: You mean I should cast to long in sqlite?

Comment: It is already long and you can use it like I show in my code. I think strftime doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `strftime` function expects the date as `text` in one of these formats:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDD.DDDD
```

You are storing the date as `integer` which `strftime` function can't handle.
More details about SQLite datetime functions [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions) (or [here](http://catalogue.pearsoned.co.uk/samplechapter/067232685X.pdf), page 80).

Comment: But this works.

date time/1000

SELECT strftime('%m-%d-%Y', 1092941466, 'unixepoch');

Comment: In my case: SELECT strftime('%m-%d-%Y', 1334262386066/1000, 'unixepoch') FROM BABY_ENTITY

Comment: OK, in this case you can use integer, 'unixepoch' modifier expects DDDDDDDDDD, which is the number of seconds since 1970. The integer you passed is interpreted as text.